# Access entities in core data

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I have 2 entities in my core data project: Land and Coordinate.
One land can have many coordinates, so it's 1 to many relationship.

To save my lands and it's coordinates I do it like this:

```
func saveToDataBase() {

   let landName:String = String(describing: Land.self)

    let land:Land = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: landName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! Land


    land.id = 1
    land.area = myLandArray[2]
    land.perimeter = myLandArray[3]
    land.lat = myLandArray[0]
    land.long = myLandArray[1]

    let coordName:String  = String(describing: Coordinate.self)
    let coord:Coordinate = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: coordName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! Coordinate

        for i in 0..<points.count {
            coord.lat = points[i].latitude
            coord.long = points[i].longitude
            land.addToRelationship(coord)  //add coordinates to its land
        }

    DatabaseController.saveContext()

    }
```

I get the lands like this:

```
func showLands() {

    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Land> = Land.fetchRequest()

    do{
        let searchResults = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
        print("Number of results: \(searchResults.count)")

        for result in searchResults as [Land]{
            print("ID: \(result.id)")
            print("Lat: \(result.lat)")
            print("Long: \(result.long)")
            print("Area: \(result.area) \(result.unArea!)")
            print("Perimeter: \(result.perimeter) \(result.unPerimeter!)")


        }
    }
    catch{
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
 }
```

How can I get coordinates for each land? I've tried a few things whithout any success :(

Here are my classes:

```
public class Coordinate: NSManagedObject {

}


extension Coordinate {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Coordinate> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Coordinate>(entityName: "Coordinate");
    }

@NSManaged public var id: Int64
@NSManaged public var lat: Double
@NSManaged public var long: Double
@NSManaged public var relationship: Land?

 }



public class Land: NSManagedObject {

}



    extension Land {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Land> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Land>(entityName: "Land");
}

@NSManaged public var area: Double
@NSManaged public var attachment: NSData?
@NSManaged public var id: Int64
@NSManaged public var lat: Double
@NSManaged public var long: Double
@NSManaged public var perimeter: Double
@NSManaged public var relationship: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for relationship
extension Land {

@objc(addRelationshipObject:)
@NSManaged public func addToRelationship(_ value: Coordinate)

@objc(removeRelationshipObject:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromRelationship(_ value: Coordinate)

@objc(addRelationship:)
@NSManaged public func addToRelationship(_ values: NSSet)

@objc(removeRelationship:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromRelationship(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

Comment: A guess would be `land.coordinates` but would need to see the `Land` and `Coordinate` classes to know for sure.

Comment: I'll show it to you

Comment: `land.relationship` will give you an NSSet that contains coordinates.

Comment: land.coordinates is what you are looking for

Comment: But how can I access every coordinate? I've tried a few things like print(" Coordinates: \(result.relationship?.allObjects)"). But I just cannot access them :( I think I added them correctly...

Comment: How can I access coordinates from land.relationship???